# Wordpress: Change Active new user

Tags: wordpress

When any user register in my site, he received an email with a message.

This message have text and link to active account.

How can edit this message ?

thankx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the plugin that will be help you.

1. [SB Welcome Email Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/welcome-email-editor/)